# InnoDB mutual table lock from two clients

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I'm stuck with the following problem and hope, that someone help me to solve it...
Mysql version 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log.

```
  CREATE TABLE `dr` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_date` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`start_date`),
  KEY `start_date` (`start_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

   CREATE TABLE `map_dr2pdu` (
  `drtable_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dr_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `packet_location` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sctp_chunk` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `dr_id` (`dr_id`),
  KEY `drtable_id` (`drtable_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

   CREATE TABLE `dr_hot` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_date` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_date` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`start_date`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;

   CREATE TABLE `map_dr2pdu_hot` (
  `drtable_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dr_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `packet_location` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sctp_chunk` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `dr_id` (`dr_id`),
  KEY `drtable_id` (`drtable_id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

`dr` and `map_dr2pdu`  have partitions (if it matters).

`dr_hot.id <===> map_dr2pdu_hot.dr_id`

There is a client **C1** (auto commit off)

- writes into `dr_hot`
- obtains **LAST_INSERTED_ID** and inserts 1-n records into `map_dr2pdu_hot`.

**C1** commit politics: 500 inserts or 1 sec (which came first)

Memory tables are introduced solely to support high insertion rate. Actual data must be store in `dr` and `map_dr2pdu` (INNODB) tables. To make this "rotation"

there is second client **C2** (auto commit off) which

1. locks `_hot` table,
2. stores its autoincrement id
3. dumps its data into file in memory,
4. truncates `_hot` table (faster, than delete)
5. updates its autoincrement id
6. commit
7. unlocks the table
8. [loads data from the file to INNODB table]

Problem appears when **C2** begins its work:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------------+---------------+----+
| Id     | User            | Host            | db        | Command | Time  | State                           | Info                                                                                                 |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+----+
|      1 | event_scheduler | localhost  | NULL | Daemon  |   1   | Waiting for next activation     | NULL                                                                                                 |
|     57 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |   283 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 115748 | root       | localhost       | riva | Query   |     0 | init                            | show processlist                                                                                     |
| 117538 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   | 10889 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120150 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |    30 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120155 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |     7 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120158 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |     5 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120161 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |     5 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120164 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |     5 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120167 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |     7 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120170 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Query   |    22 | Waiting for table metadata lock | ALTER TABLE dr_hot AUTO_INCREMENT=1152885790                                                  |
| 120178 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |     5 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120179 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Query   |    23 | Waiting for table metadata lock | LOCK TABLES map_dr2pdu_hot LOW_PRIORITY WRITE                                                       |
| 120243 | riva       | localhost       | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120244 | riva       | localhost:40934 | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120245 | riva       | localhost:40935 | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120246 | riva       | localhost:40936 | riva | Sleep   |    22 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120247 | riva       | localhost:40937 | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120248 | riva       | localhost:40938 | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120249 | riva       | localhost:40939 | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120250 | riva       | localhost:40940 | riva | Sleep   |    24 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120251 | riva       | localhost:40941 | riva | Sleep   |    22 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120252 | riva       | localhost:40942 | riva | Sleep   |    22 |                                 | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 120253 | riva       | localhost:40943 | riva | Execute |    22 | Waiting for table metadata lock | INSERT INTO map_dr2pdu_hot   (xdrtable_id, xdr_id, packet_location) VALUES   (25, 6078, |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------+---------+-------+---------------------------------+------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql general_log + processlist:

```
 119177 Execute  INSERT INTO map_dr2pdu_hot   (drtable_id, dr_id, packet_location) VALUES   (26, 131287232, 606
4773029186237937)
119177 Query    COMMIT
119453 Query    LOCK TABLES map_dr2pdu_hot WRITE

processlist:
| 119453 | rivasense       | localhost        | rivasense | Query   |  164 | Waiting for table metadata lock | LOCK TABLES map_dr2pdu_hot WRITE                                                                                                 

119177 Query    START TRANSACTION
119177 Execute  INSERT INTO dr_hot   ()
```

Show engine innodb status, does not show any deadlock, just like

```
mysql> select * from INNODB_LOCKS;
Empty set (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from INNODB_LOCK_WAITS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

As I understoo : `C1` acquires lock for insert and seems not commits, but it DOES according to log. therefore, `C2` can't lock table.

Please help to find the root cause.

**update on 06/10/14:**
Basically problem reproducible when **C1** tries to write something into `map_dr2pdu_hot` and **C2** simultaneously tries to lock the same table. This treated as "almost" deadlock (not listed among deadlocks) and released with lock_wait_timeout expired.

Could you suggest how to resolve such a problem?

Comment: read this : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/what-are-reasons-not-to-use-the-memory-storage-engine-in-mysql

Comment: we have to use in mem tables, because when they used as buffer between app and innodb (disk) tables allow increasing insertion rate 3+x times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we had to apply WA - modify algorithm of C2 to:

1. stores _hot tbl autoincrement id
2. dumps its data into file in memory,
3. deletes from _hot table (where id less than auto inc id from step 1)
4. loads data from the file to INNODB table

of course map_dr2pdu table altered to have id auto-increment column.